Discrete log of Goldilocks, Babybear, and Mersenne31 fields
Does anyone know if the discrete log problem of these small prime fields: Goldilocks, Babybear, Mersenne31, has been solved?
If not, is there a small prime field in which the discrete log of any element can be computed in poly-logarithmic time of the order of the field?
Quote from https://blog.icme.io/small-fields-for-zero-knowledge/


Polygon's 'Plonky2' uses a field defined as $p = 2^{64} - 2^{32}  + 1$, which is called the Goldilocks field.
The zkVM Risc0 uses a smaller field called BabyBear defined as: $p = 15 \cdot 2^{27} + 1$.
Plonky3: utilizes one even smaller Mersenne31: $p = 2^{31} - 1 .$ (1772, Leonhard Euler)



The DLP in these small prime fields is quite easy. E.g. for $p=2^{64}-2^{32}+1$, the largest prime factor of $p-1$ is $q=65537$, thus the Pohlig–Hellman algorithm applies, and it's cost is dominated by computing the DLP in a subgroup of that order $q$, requiring in the order of $2^{17}$ modular multiplications. That can be done in a fraction of a second by a single PC.
The current record is a 795-bit $p$, and with $(p-1)/2$ prime, which makes the problem much more difficult. See this related question and e.g. this reference an answer gives.
However, solving the DLP in a prime field $\mathbb F_p$ does not imply solving the DLP in field $\mathbb F_{p^k}$ for suitably large $k$, much less in an elliptic curve group over such kind of field, which is what the linked article is about.

Although the OP asked this, this is not an issue there. They deliberately choose these to speed as long as the attacker's time is not faster.

That's right, we are looking for speed. Specifically, we are looking for a prime field with order p > 2^32, and for any given a, we can quickly  (as fast as possible, best if in log(p) time ) find x s.t. g^a +g^x =1, where g is the generator. Any idea if is it possible?

@Jason: if you can afford about 1MB of precomputed hash tables, then prime $p=r, s+1$ with $r=65587$, $s=2^{16}$, and $g=2$ will do with a simplified version of Pohlig–Hellman. You tabulate $\left(g^r\right)^i\bmod p$ for $0\le i<s$ and $\left(g^s\right)^j\bmod p$ for $0\le j<r$. Then for given $a$, compute $b=1-g^a\bmod p$, search $b^r\bmod p$ in the first table to find $i=x\bmod s$ and search $b^s\bmod p$ in the second table to find $j=x\bmod r$, then compute $x$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, e.g. as $x=((r^{-1}\bmod s)(i-j)\bmod s)r+j$.

@fgrieu: Thank you, really appreciate your help.

@Jason The answer is right on the question. You should accept it and upvote it when you have enough reputation.
